# Add object to a cart

Tags: ios, objective-c, magento

In my app I'm using Magento to create an e-commerce store. To use Magento I'm using this library [LogNMagento](https://github.com/lognllc/LogNMagento). With this library I'm connecting correctly to Magento server, I'm creating a cart and now I need to add a product to the cart I just created. To add a product to this cart I'm using this code:

```
- (void)createCarriageWithProductID:(NSString *)productID {
    Magento.service.storeID = @1;
    [Magento.service startSession];
    self.qty = @1;
    [Magento call:@[@"cart.create"]
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              Magento.service.cartID = responseObject;
              NSLog(@"cartID: %@", Magento.service.cartID);
              self.cartId = Magento.service.cartID;
              [Magento call:@[@"cart_product.add", @{
                                  @"quoteId": Magento.service.cartID,
                                  @"products": @[productID, self.qty]
                                  }]
                    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                        NSLog(@"Prodotto aggiunto");
                    }
                    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                        NSLog(@"error cart_product.add: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                    }];
          }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"error cart.create: %@", error.localizedDescription);
          }];
}
```

But when I try to run the app and to add the product to the cart I'm getting this messages:

```
2013-11-18 11:54:33.549 BitmamaShop[1410:70b] got session b483cf4f44cab768806642ba9a92b405
2013-11-18 11:54:34.701 BitmamaShop[1410:70b] cartID: 41
2013-11-18 11:54:35.660 BitmamaShop[1410:70b] error cart_product.add: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

The first 2 messages shows me that the app is working correctly with the Magento store, but when I try to do next operation it shows me the last message. I guess that this problem is because I'm not creating correctly the request to add product.
To know which API I'm using you can go [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html) to know how `cart_create.add` API works. Can you help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found looked at the XML that I'm sending by using php and I compared it with the XML I was sending to the web server, so I solved in this way:

```
#import "CreateCarriage.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Magento.h"

@implementation CreateCarriage

- (void)createCarriageWithProductID:(NSString *)productID {
    Magento.service.storeID = @1;
    [Magento.service startSession];
    if (!appDelegate.cartID) {
        [Magento call:@[@"cart.create"]
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                  Magento.service.cartID = responseObject;
                  NSLog(@"cartID: %@", Magento.service.cartID);
                  self.cartId = Magento.service.cartID;
                  [Magento call:@[@"cart_product.add", Magento.service.cartID,@[@{@"product_id": productID, @"qty": self.qty}]]
                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                            NSLog(@"Prodotto aggiunto");
                            [Magento call:@[@"cart.info", @{@"quoteId": Magento.service.cartID}]
                                  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                      [self getListOfProductsInCart:responseObject];
                                  }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                      NSLog(@"Errore: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                  }];

                        }
                        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"error cart_product.add: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                        }];
              }
              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"error cart.create: %@", error.localizedDescription);
              }];
    } else {
        [Magento call:@[@"cart_product.add", appDelegate.cartID,@[@{@"product_id": productID, @"qty": self.qty}]]
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                  NSLog(@"Prodotto aggiunto");
                  [Magento call:@[@"cart.info", @{@"quoteId": Magento.service.cartID}]
                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                            [self getListOfProductsInCart:responseObject];
                        }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"Errore: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                        }];

              }
              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"error cart_product.add: %@", error.localizedDescription);
              }];
    }
}

- (void)getListOfProductsInCart:(id)productList {
    NSDictionary *dictCart = productList;
    NSArray *items = [dictCart objectForKey:@"items"];
    NSLog(@"%d", items.count);
//    NSDictionary *dictItems = [items firstObject];
//    NSLog(@"name: %@\nqty: %@", [dictItems objectForKey:@"name"], [dictItems objectForKey:@"qty"]);

}
```

In this way I generate the correct XML and I add the product to the cart. In the code I mapped too a method to get the information of the cart. I hope it will useful for someone.